# Migrating react project dependencies from node to apache

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, reactjs, create-react-app

I have created a react application using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)
 but I want to move my application from node to apache and I'm not sure how to handle my project's dependencies. For instance, [material-ui's](http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/installation]) documentation only lists npm on its installation guide.

Is there a way to get these dependencies to work on an apache server?

If so, would it be a separate configuration process for each dependency?

```
package.json

{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "material-ui": "^0.18.6",
    "npm": "^5.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-flexbox-grid": "^1.1.3",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to use npm packages at apache? Which programming language are you going to use? Pure html and javascript?

Comment: Yep! I'd like to use these npm packages with apache. I'll also be using a bit of PHP. To clarify, I already have an apache server running that serves some php files, and I want apache to serve my react application as well. I'm building a web portfolio site, and I'd like to structure it with react while also being able to show past projects built with php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React applications don't depend on any particular server technology - once your build has run, it's just static JavaScript.

Running `npm run build` in your project's root will create a `dist` folder with your bundled application inside - all you need to do is deploy the contents of that folder to your Apache server.

[See the 'Deploying' section of the `create-react-app` README for more info.](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment)

As an aside - if you've been using `create-react-app`'s built-in server in production, don't! That's just designed for development, and is not performant nor secure enough for serving your app to the world.

Comment: @JesseHuang: No problem, glad I could help! Make sure you have a read through the rest of that README file too, there's a load of really helpful stuff in there.